# iptables MARK works to change gateway, CONNMARK does not

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I have a routing table which sends some traffic from another host out a different, higher speed gateway

```
ip route show table 88
default via 192.168.88.1 dev eno3
192.168.88.0/24 dev eno3 scope link src 192.168.88.4
```

And a routing rule which forwards upon a packet mark being set:

```
32765:  from all fwmark 0x58 lookup 88
```

I have an iptables rule to route some traffic over this connection.

```
*mangle
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.10.2 --sport 12345 -j MARK --set-mark 88
-A PREROUTING -p udp -s 192.168.10.2 --sport 12345 -j MARK --set-mark 88
COMMIT
```

This rule works fine, but long lived connections lose their mark and end up getting routed over the default gateway instead of the high speed one.

I try setting the rule to CONNMARK instead:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.10.2 --sport 12345 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 88
-A PREROUTING -p udp -s 192.168.10.2 --sport 12345 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 88
```

The packets are being marked (as shown in `iptables -L -vv -t mangle`), but they're going out the wrong gateway.

How do I fix my issue? I am on Debian.

The underlying issue is: Any connection with a source port of 12345 and a source host of 1.2.3.4 should go out that gateway, along with everything subsequent in the lifespan of that connection.

Traffic in question is mostly UDP

Comment: Not exactly familiar with the matter but AFAIK MARK/fwmark has nothing to do with connection. I don't think `but long lived connections lose their mark and end up getting routed over the default gateway instead of the high speed one` is the actual reason for what you are experiencing. Maybe it has something to do with `rp_filter`? (Btw `CONNMARK` is a total different thing and is not checked by ip rules.)